# Node.js browser error Cannot GET/

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm quite new to Node, I've been following a tutorial to build a simple server that serves dynamic pags with some basic routes but keep getting the `Error: Cannot GET/` after running `node server.js` and calling localhost:3300 on the browser. My routes are defined externally and initialized using a `routes.initialise()` as follows:

```
//routes.js
var home = require('../controllers/home'),
image = require('../controllers/image'),
express = require('express');

module.exports.initialize = function(app, router) {
//var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', home.index);
router.get('/images/:image_id', image.index);
router.post('/images', image.create);
router.post('/images/:image_id/like', image.like);
router.post('/images/:image_id/comment', image.comment);

app.use('/', router);
};
```

I've searched far and wide but no solution forthcoming. I'm really frustrated and will need some help here.

I have a server.js that creates the server:

```
//server.js
var express = require('express'), 
config = require('./server/configure'),    
app = express(); 

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3300); 
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app = config(app);


var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {    
console.log('Server up: http://localhost:' + app.get('port')); 
});
```

and a configure.js that configures the server:

```
//configure.js
var path = require('path'),
routes = require('./routes'),
exphbs = require('express3-handlebars'),
express = require('express'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
cookieParser = require('cookie-parser'),
morgan = require('morgan'),
methodOverride = require('method-override'),
errorHandler = require('errorhandler');

module.exports = function(app) {
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs.create({
    defaultLayout: 'main',
    layoutsDir: app.get('views') + '/layouts',
    partialsDir: [app.get('views') + '/partials']
}).engine);

app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser({
    uploadDir:path.join(__dirname, 'public/upload/temp')
}));

app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser('some-secret-value-here'));
routes.initialize(app, new express.Router());

app.use('/public/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));

if ('development' === app.get('env')) {
    app.use(errorHandler());
}

return app;
};
```

also two files, `home.js` and `image.js` which are supposed to provide the default routes from configure.js:

```
//home.js
module.exports = {
index: function(req, res) {
    res.send('The home:index controller');
}
};

//image.js
module.exports = {    
index: function(req, res) {        
    res.send('The image:index controller ' + req.params.image_id);    
},

create: function(req, res) {        
    res.send('The image:create POST controller');    
},    

like: function(req, res) {        
    res.send('The image:like POST controller');    
},    

comment: function(req, res) {        
    res.send('The image:comment POST controller');    
} 
};
```

Anytime I try to GET any of the links on the browser it returns the Cannot GET/ error. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much :)

Comment: can you put the code onto github so I can try from there? This is kind of a lot to copy and paste correctly.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I don't use Github. It's just five files: server.js, configure.js, image.js, home.js and routes.js.

Comment: put it on dropbox or some file share

Comment: okay I just did. uploaded the entire folder (and structure) without the node_modules folder though: https://app.box.com/s/792ulcvav9bgsmazslnhvrxz021qw3f4

Answer (score 1):

I actually copied your exact code and it worked as you expect, though frankly it's got a bunch of indirection and at least one deprecated module. Maybe you have a PORT environmental variable set, and so the app isn't actually running on 3300?

Comment: I tried to change the PORT variable to 3300 using set PORT, still same error. I don't even know if that's what I'm supposed to do. Please more help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I literally downloaded your files and ran npm install and then node server and it runs.  Do you get the console output like: `Server up: http://localhost:3300`?

Comment: Yeah, it runs on the console. But when I try `http://localhost:3300` on the browser, it keeps returning Error: Cannot GET/. For some reason it's not GETting the responses. Also on console it returns Error 404.

Comment: RIght, but what I'm saying is that it runs, *and* I can GET the page at /.  I receive a HTTP 200 response with the text "The home:index controller"

Comment: What I'm saying is that I can't. I constantly receive a `Cannot GET/` response. I'm so frustrated. Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Nvm guys I got it running now. I think it's something to do with my directory structure. Didn't realize how important this was. Thanks guys